# Bcrypt comparing passwords results to undefined error in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am setting up a simple login with passport
an error occurs while trying to compare user password with saved password

```
module.exports = function (passport) {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
        let query = { email: username };

        User.find(query, function (err, user) {

            if (err) { 
                console.log(err); 
            }
            else {
                if (!user) {
                    console.log(3)
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'No user found' })
                } else {
                    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                        } else {
                            console.log(user.password)

                            if (isMatch) {
                                console.log(5)
                                return done(null, user);
                            } else {
                                console.log(6)
                                return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong Password' })
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }

        })
    }));
```

when I `console.log(user)`:

```
[ { _id: 5c5995448a88110c35673bb7,
    firstname: 'test',
    lastname: 'sample',
    email: 'testsample@gmail.com',
    password:
     '$2b$10$bDVGjce/aDxr/NzXFw.qO.DA4tKjY6EwMARgl/NZfb0FNTaTxYwCW',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

but using bcrypt, `user.password` results to `undefined` while trying to compare saved password with the form's `password` entry, yet, seemingly the password has been received from the query results, as evident in `console.log(user)` results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since mongoDB is returning 'user' as an array with a single item you can either:

```
module.exports = function (passport) {
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    let query = { email: username };

    User.find(query, function (err, user) {

        if (err) { 
            console.log(err); 
        }
        else {
            if (!user) {
                console.log(3)
                return done(null, false, { message: 'No user found' })
            } else {
                bcrypt.compare(password, user[0].password, function (err, isMatch) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(user[0].password)

                        if (isMatch) {
                            console.log(5)
                            return done(null, user);
                        } else {
                            console.log(6)
                            return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong Password' })
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }

    })
}));
```

or you could

```
module.exports = function (passport) {
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
let query = { email: username };

User.find(query, function (err, user) {

    if (err) { 
        console.log(err); 
    }
    else {
        if (!user) {
            console.log(3)
            return done(null, false, { message: 'No user found' })
        } else {
            let userdata = user[0];
            bcrypt.compare(password, userdata.password, function (err, isMatch) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(userdata.password)

                    if (isMatch) {
                        console.log(5)
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        console.log(6)
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong Password' })
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

})
}));
```

Comment: no worries, it's a pleasure - If it helped you, you are welcome to upvote my answer ;)

Comment: I'm still a newbie in the forum, apparently stackoverflow doesnt recognize my votes :-D But I appreciate your help.